# Как запускать определенное кол-во потоков?

Tags: python

Имею файл в 10к записей. Как запускать 10 потоков для каждые 10 записей. То есть, чтоб было не больше 10 потоков.

Имею такой код:

```
from threading import Thread
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from fuzzywuzzy import process



def get_list_data(input_file_name):
    '''Получение списка товаров из файла'''
    list_data = []
    wb = load_workbook(filename=input_file_name)
    sheet = wb.active
    m_row = sheet.max_row
    with open('conf/alias.txt', 'r') as file_alias:
        list_alias = []
        for item in file_alias:
            # if ',' in item:
            #     list_alias.append(item.title().replace(
            #         '\n', '').split(',')[-1])
            # else:
            list_alias.append(item.title().replace('\n', ''))

    for i in range(1, m_row+1):
        if not sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value:
            continue
        title = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value).replace("'", '')
        brand_s = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value).replace(
            "'", '').rstrip().title().split(' ')
        point_match = process.extractOne(brand_s[0], list_alias)
        alias = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value).replace("'", '').rstrip().title()
        if point_match is not None:
            if point_match[-1] >= 50:
                alias = point_match[0]

        brand = '+'.join(brand_s)
        min_count = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value).replace("'", '')
        max_time_delivery = str(sheet.cell(
            row=i, column=4).value).replace("'", '')
        count_sell = str(sheet.cell(
            row=i, column=5).value).replace("'", '')
        object = {'idnp': title, 'brand': brand, 'min_count': min_count,
                  'max_time_delivery': max_time_delivery, 'count_sell': count_sell, 'alias': alias}
        list_data.append(object)

    return list_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
  list_data = get_list_data('Копия китай.xlsx')

  for index,item in enumerate(list_data):
    print(index)
```

Была идея сделать так: запустить цикл по списку с шагом 10 и создавать поток на `i,i-1,i-2,...,i-10` записей. Но с enumerate такое сделать не получается. Была еще идея: добавлять в список индексы записей уже которые были в потоках и каждый раз проверять, но это слишком тупо. Подскажите как сделать правильно.

Вот ссылка на исходник: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/572o/pU2nd1a5M

А что должно получится это не имеет значения, просто мне нужно понять как эти 10 потоков запустить

Comment: А в чем у Вас проблема с Вашим кодом? Зачем вы хотите файл в несколько потоков обрабатывать хотите? Медленно обрабатывает?

Comment: Создается впечатление, что вы пытаетесь из csv дописать данные в файл excel. Если это так, то это проще делается.

Comment: @Namerek Насчет файла csv: я там csv не использую, данные из файла excel переходят в файл excel, это если коротко) "А в чем у Вас проблема с Вашим кодом? Зачем вы хотите файл в несколько потоков обрабатывать хотите? Медленно обрабатывает?" Да медленно обрабатывает. У меня в исходном файле в каждой строке есть значения которые нужны для составления url'a, этот url нужен для парсинга, вот. В одном потоке это все обрабатывать как-то не очень. И хочу ускорить процесс. Думаю вы поняли меня

Comment: Да вполне понятно. Пример исходника можете в вопрос добавить и пример желаемого результата?

Comment: @Namerek Добавил исходник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам и не нужны потоки. Я вижу как минимум две возможности ускорить этот код:

- Вынести чтение и парсинг файла **'conf/alias.txt'** из функции. Он у вас вроде нигде не меняется в процессе работы программы. Читайте файл заранее и передавайте в функцию `get_list_data` готовый список псевдонимов.
- Использовать по мере возможности кэширование, чтобы не дёргать насколько я понимаю весьма затратную по времени функцию `fuzzywuzzy.process.extractOne`.

Примерно так:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def extract_one(name):
    process.extractOne(name, list_alias)

# ...
point_match = extract_one(brand_s[0])
```

Конечно, тут надо `list_alias` сформировать сразу и сделать доступным глобально. Можно его и в качестве аргумента функции `extract_one` передавать, но лучше не надо, чтобы не загружать кэш лишней информацией и проверками.

В принципе, можно и ещё какие-то куски кода вынести в кэширующие декораторы, но это надо ещё думать. Если у вас часто повторяются одни и те же строки в `brand_s[0]` ускорение при таком кэшировании должно быть весьма неплохим.

Но если захотите всё же использовать потоки, то проще всего использовать `Pool` из модуля `multiprocessing`, там всё просто. Пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Благодарю, уже начал использовал ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @Евгений Попробуйте всё же при случае кэширование. Там надо, конечно, думать, что вынести в кэш, как его настроить и т.д., но иногда очень хорошо взлетает даже без настроек,

Comment: Попробую, спасибо